# How to run Laravel queue:work in shared hosting without overlapping

Tags: laravel, cron

How to run Laravel queue:work in shared hosting without overlapping

i am using this code in a cronjob but this is using too much CPU resource due to overlapping command
what is the best way to do this.

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/electro/public_html/artisan queue:work
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of high CPU is caused because the worker loads the complete framework everytime it checks for a job in the queue.

**You can use:**

`php artisan queue:work --daemon`

**in your case:**

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/electro/public_html/artisan queue:work --daemon`

This will load the framework once and the checking/processing of jobs happen inside a while loop, which lets CPU breathe easy.

Comment: why after some days queue worker stopped how to run it continuously and if server restated it also start automatically.

how to check running queue work?

Answer (score 1):

Late to this but people are still looking for an answer

Create an entry on app\Console\Kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')
             ->everyMinute()
             ->withoutOverlapping();
```

This will fire a queue worker once per minute, but then stop when the queue has been emptied.  If there are a lot of jobs (more than one minutes worth) then the ->withoutOverlapping prevents the scheduler from starting another worker.